# Unable to unmask more than one frame in web socket

Tags: php, phpwebsocket

I have a problem with receiving frames via socket_recv in PHP server. Problem appears when I send more than 1 messages from client in one time (e.g for loop)

If loop is of 10 times than I am getting return only 1 in decMessages & when i print payload it display only 2 messages at a time.

```
function unmask($payload) {


$tempCount=0;
$decMessages = Array();  
do 
{ // This should be running until all frames are unmasked and added to $decMessages Array 
    $tempCount++;
    $length = ord($payload[1]) & 127;
    $temp_variable = 0;
    if($length == 126) {
      $temp_variable = 4;   
      $masks = substr($payload, 4, 4);
      $data = substr($payload, 8);
      $len = (ord($payload[2]) << 8) + ord($payload[3]);
    }elseif($length == 127) {
      $temp_variable = 14;  
      $masks = substr($payload, 10, 4);
      $data = substr($payload, 14);
      $len = (ord($payload[2]) << 56) + (ord($payload[3]) << 48) +
          (ord($payload[4]) << 40) + (ord($payload[5]) << 32) +
          (ord($payload[6]) << 24) +(ord($payload[7]) << 16) +
          (ord($payload[8]) << 8) + ord($payload[9]);
    }else {        
      $temp_variable = 6;       
      $masks = substr($payload, 2, 4);
      $data = substr($payload, 6);
      $len = $length;
    }

    $payload = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {    
      $payload .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    echo "This is payload".$payload."\n\r";
    echo "This is Count ".count($decMessages)."\n\r";
    echo "This is temp ".$tempCount."\n\r";

    $decMessages[] = $payload;


    $payload = substr($payload, $len+$temp_variable, strlen($payload));     
}
while (($len < strlen($data)) && $tempCount<10);

//echo "\n" . count($decMessages) . "\n";

return $decMessages;
```

}

Comment: I would guess that your while loop condition is not behaving as expected.  Trying to work out why from reading that code is pretty tough.  I'd start at the while condition and work back from there.

Comment: Can you provide a $payload example so it is possible to run the code snippet?

Comment: The while condition break automatically even when temp count reach to two, and the out put i got after that are the strange characters

Comment: For payload i am taking more than 141 characters string@Dag Sondre

Comment: i am trying to send data from IoT device and receiving it on php server because of  Nagle's Algorithm, i getting more then two packets together which i want to unmask and display it on browser

Answer (score 0):

You have replaced the data of the $payload variable with unmasked data. I added new $text variable.

```
function unmask($payload) {

$tempCount=0;
$decMessages = Array();  
do 
{ // This should be running until all frames are unmasked and added to $decMessages Array 
    $tempCount++;
    $length = ord($payload[1]) & 127;
    $temp_variable = 0;
    if($length == 126) {
      $temp_variable = 4;   
      $masks = substr($payload, 4, 4);
      $data = substr($payload, 8);
      $len = (ord($payload[2]) << 8) + ord($payload[3]);
    }elseif($length == 127) {
      $temp_variable = 14;  
      $masks = substr($payload, 10, 4);
      $data = substr($payload, 14);
      $len = (ord($payload[2]) << 56) + (ord($payload[3]) << 48) +
          (ord($payload[4]) << 40) + (ord($payload[5]) << 32) +
          (ord($payload[6]) << 24) +(ord($payload[7]) << 16) +
          (ord($payload[8]) << 8) + ord($payload[9]);
    }else {        
      $temp_variable = 6;       
      $masks = substr($payload, 2, 4);
      $data = substr($payload, 6);
      $len = $length;
    }

    $text = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {    
      $text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
    }
    echo "This is text ".$text."\n\r";
    echo "This is Count ".count($decMessages)."\n\r";
    echo "This is temp ".$tempCount."\n\r";

    $decMessages[] = $text;    

    $payload = substr($payload, $len+$temp_variable, strlen($payload));     
}
while (($len < strlen($data)) && $tempCount<10);

//echo "\n" . count($decMessages) . "\n";

return $decMessages;
```